# Is there a connection between the subsystems of second-order arithmetic and computational complexity?

Tags: computational-complexity, reverse-math

The ["big five subsystems of second-order arithmetic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) in reverse arithmetic reveal the stratification of the structure of mathematics. What if any is the connection of these strata with [complexity classes](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo)?

Comment: Even an NP problem can be solved recursively, so all the complexity of the usual classes is buried in RCA_0.  Beyond that, there are obviously many maps from the five subsystems of second-order arithmetic to complexity classes that preserve (non-)inclusion, but I don't know of any that are insightful.